# "Expected 1 arguments, but got 0." for onClick event in React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a handleClick function that I'm trying to pass as a prop for my onClick event within a component. This event just takes a setState function. I set an interface to type this as "handleClick: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction>;" as nothing else worked and would always give errors, so I assumed all was well, until I went ahead with writing the onClick event into the component declaration, when the error in the title appeared.

Here's the relevant code:

```
interface IProps {
    handleClick: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
    icon?: JSX.Element;
}

const NavLinks: React.FC<IProps> = ({ handleClick }) => (
    <div className="sidebar_navlinks">
        {sidebar_links.map((link) => (
            <NavLink key={link.name}  to={link.to} onClick={() => handleClick && handleClick()}>
                <div className="link">
                    <link.icon className="icon" />
                    {link.name}
                </div>
            </NavLink>
        ))}
    </div>
)
```

And then with that component I just do something like

```
<NavLinks handleClick={() => setMenuState(false)} />
```

How can I best type this so it stops giving the error in the title? I'm not clear why it would expect there's a value when I'm typed it to be something that sets state?

I see stuff online that, more often than not, is assuming the onClick is going to apply to an HTML button element, but I'm just using this to click on react-icons, so I'm even more lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`handleClick` should be of type `() => void` since `setMenuState` is wrapped in a function.

```
interface IProps {
    handleClick: () => void;
    icon?: JSX.Element;
}
```

If you passed `setMenuState` directly like:
`<NavLinks handleClick={setMenuState} />`
then it can be typed as a setState function

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick, and I'm so confused why since I thought I had already tried that earlier and it kept giving type errors. In any case, it works now. Guess I better get used to this...